# Перевод даты из строки в Unix

Tags: php

я получаю дату такого формата

```
 string(10) "19 05 2016"
```

мне надо её перевести в unix формат пробую так

```
var_dump(strtotime($post["Serial"]["dataseria"]))
```

получаю

```
bool(false)
```

почему так не подскажите ? И как правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости, ваша дата не соответствует формату, ожидаемому функцией `strtotime`. Думаю стоит указывать формат в явном виде. Например так:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d m Y', '19 05 2016');
echo($date->getTimestamp());
```

Рабочий [пример](http://ideone.com/v3q686) на IDEOne.

Comment: bool(false)  получаю

Comment: Значит вы что-то делаете не так (код в ответе - работает, ссылка на пруф там тоже есть) .